# Bitnami Stack : accessing wordpress installation in its own directory at domain root

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory, bitnami

Please Bear With Me!!

i am using this tutorial [Giving Wordpress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) (Using a pre-existing subdirectory install part ) to launch a wordpress (installed at a sub folder called wordpress) by using example.com instead of example.com/wordpress.

Now it says that copy index.php to your root folder and change the relative path to wp-blog-header.php accordingly now by folder structure is a little complex hence i have attached a pic[image: This is the pic]

Now to access site root i go to example.com(obvious)
but to access wordpress i have to go to example.com/wordpress (if anyone wondering why i am using bitnami wordpress stack AMI and thus everything came preconfigured)

now accoringly to tutorial i should copy index.php to site root from wordpress root and change relative location of wp-blog-header.php accordingly.
when index.php was in same directory the function was `require('./wp-blog-header.php')` . Now this location is to be changed

I have tried all three options i could think of (i guess)

1) ../apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php

2)./wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php

3)wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php

Edit : its a bitmani wordpress stack ami on amazon aws and its the reason i believe there is problem in the first place.

But visiting the domain root gives server error . Any suggesstions??

Answer (score 0):

Try `require ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wherever/wp-blog-header.php/is/located` and it should find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Apache#How_to_change_the_URL.3f
it was because of bitnami and not a fault of wordpress